# Return a 2D array inside a struct of arrays

Tags: arrays, function, struct, return, dynamic-allocation

I am working with a function that modifies my array of structs called match by reallocating match and making it one struct bigger:

```
match = realloc(match, (sizeof(mStruct)*num_matches+1));
```

The struct prototype is as follows:

```
typedef struct{
    char **names;
    int score;
    int diff; 
} mStruct;
```

The problem is once I allocate memory inside the struct for an array of char pointers for their respective char arrays, the char pointers are never returned to the calling function since i'm returning type mStruct.

```
return match;
```

The rest of the statically declared variables are returned since they don't need special pointers to them. How would I go about  returning the char pointers?

My the called functions parameters are as follows:

```
mStruct* trigger(pStruct *mArr, pStruct *wArr, mStruct *match)
```

The calling function looks like this

```
match = trigger(mArr, wArr, match);
```